# Error when creating a wallet using kin.js

Tags: typescript2.0, kin

Trying to embed kin.js in an Ionic App, I can see that the key creation using Keypairs and network initialization is ok

```
const keys = Keypair.random();
const network = KinNetwork.Production;
```

However when I try to create the wallet

```
createWallet(network, keys)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

It keeps retrying but at the end it replies with Error: failed to load account:

I can see the API call is made
https://horizon-kin-ecosystem.kininfrastructure.com/accounts/GANWXV7IHG6YGWVIXJNB56OCBIYI7LYKD34CH556YCDOP5LRC2WDJLTC?c=0.32263221858689695
but the response includes this object

```
{
 “type”: “https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/not_found",
 “title”: “Resource Missing”,
 “status”: 404,
 “detail”: “The resource at the url requested was not found. This is usually occurs for one of two reasons: The url requested is not valid, or no data in our database could be found with the parameters provided.”
}
```

Any missing parameters I should supply beyond the network and keys

Comment: The problem is that your wallet is funded. Currently, there's no way to do that outside of our ecosystem.

Comment: * isn't funded...

Comment: Is it possible at least to try on testnet

Comment: you can use the friendbot to create and fund an account on the blockchain (only on testnet): https://friendbot-playground.kininfrastructure.com/?addr=%3Cpublic there's not much documentation on that, but you can read a bit [here](https://kinecosystem.github.io/kin-website-docs/docs/kin-architecture-overview.html#friendbot) and [here](https://kin-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fee-faucet/). Note that you need to do that **before** you use the kin.js `createWallet`.